# Seleniumでページを取得できないサイトがある

Tags: python, python3, selenium

下記サイトにchromedriverとseleniumを用いてアクセスしようと試みています。
他のサイトでは問題なくアクセスできていますが、getで処理が止まってしまいます。

https://salonboard.com/login/

【環境】
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Python 3.10.12
Google Chrome 116.0.5845.110
Selenium 4.14.0

```
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import time

CHROMEDRIVER = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://salonboard.com/login"

    service = Service(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER)
    #ヘッドレスモードでブラウザを起動
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    #ブラウザを起動
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    # urlにアクセス
    print('before get')
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        print('after get')
    except Exception as e:
        print('timeout')
    finally:
        #ブラウザ停止
        driver.quit()
```

【出力】

```
before get
timeout
```

Comment: `options.add_argument('--headless')`を外すとまた別のエラーメッセージは出ますが処理は進むようですね。

Comment: Linux(CUI)環境なのでヘッドレスモードは必須と思っています。

Comment: `options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla.途中省略."')`を指定してみてはどうでしょう？ 同様に別のエラーメッセージは出ますが処理は進むようです。最初のコメントも含めてどちらもWindows上で試しているので状況は違うかもしれませんが。

Comment: 試してみます。確かにユーザーエージェントを見るjavascriptの処理が含まれているので関係ありそうですね。

Comment: @kunif ご教示の通りユーザーエージェントを指定することで解決できました。ありがとうございます。"Mozilla.途中省略."の””は不要のようでした。

Comment: そうしたらその内容を自己回答としてみてください。[自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

ユーザーエージェントを指定することで解決できました。

```
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
import time

CHROMEDRIVER = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://salonboard.com/login"

    service = Service(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER)
    #ヘッドレスモードでブラウザを起動
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
    #ブラウザを起動
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
    print(agent)
    # urlにアクセス
    print('before get')
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        print('after get')
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    finally:
        #ブラウザ停止
        driver.quit()
```

【出力】
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
before get
after get